# how to call method statically if object and class name is same in java

Tags: java

```
class SomeClass
{
    static public void someStaticMethod(){};
}

SomeClass SomeClass=new SomeClass();
SomeClass.someStaticMethod();
```

How to call the static method of any class where object name is same as class name?

Comment: Does this even pass compilation?

Comment: Why would you have the `class name` and `object name` same on the first place?

Comment: prepend the package name to the class. i.e `com.mypackage.SomeClass.someStaticMethod();`

Comment: Also: the object name should explain why this object exists. If it's just a random `someClass` then it shouldn't exist anyway. Is it the "target" of something, the "source", the "frobnicator"? Having variable names that are equal to class names (even if they differ in case) is a slight code smell in my opinion.

Comment: @Isaac yes, that is what made me curious

Comment: This compiles and executes as expected. Clearly you didn't even try it. Not a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do anything - it will work as is (although it makes little sense to use such a confusing code).

How ambiguous names are handled is specified in the [JLS #6.5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.2). In particular:

> If the AmbiguousName is a simple name, consisting of a single Identifier:
>
> - If the Identifier appears within the scope (§6.3) of a local variable declaration (§14.4) or parameter declaration (§8.4.1, §8.8.1, §14.20) or field declaration (§8.3) with that name, then the AmbiguousName is reclassified as an ExpressionName.
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if a type of that name is declared in the compilation unit (§7.3) containing the Identifier, either by a single-type-import declaration (§7.5.1), or by a type-import-on-demand declaration (§7.5.2), or by a single-static-import declaration (§7.5.3), or by a static-import-on-demand declaration (§7.5.4), then the AmbiguousName is reclassified as a TypeName.

So in your case, `SomeClass` will be the variable you declared one line above, which has priority over types.

Answer (score 3):

The variable name should not be capitalized, hence you would have:

```
SomeClass.someStaticMethod();
```

for the static one and:

```
someClass.someNonStaticMethod();
```

for the non-static versions.

Answer (score 0):

Do not start instance names with capital letter !

You should write :

```
SomeClass someClass=new SomeClass();
```

or better yet :

```
SomeClass someObject=new SomeClass();
```

If you follow these very common rules, you won't have this issue.
(I'm trying to guess where this '-1' comes from !!!)

Comment: yes, i know. but i am curious if there is any other way around or not as stating both class and object same does not show any compilation error.

Comment: Well you should try by youself and tell us the answers. However, this is only possible if you keep this very bad coding habits... (the -1 just disappeared ;) never mind)